# Is a dice more random than a coin?

Tags: statistics, dice, random

My roommate and I have gotten into an argument.  I presented him with the question is a dice, with half of the sides numbered 1 and the other half numbered 2, more random than just flipping a coin?  Statistically we agree that the chance is 1/2 either way.  But I am arguing that a dice is better as a random generating object then the coin.  My idea is that if both the coin and the dice were thrown, the coin would land and be finished "rolling" before the dice was done generating its number.  With more computation time, the dice would be more random.  My question then becomes, is a dice or any other object just better at randomly generating numbers? Would a person have a much easier time creating a random event with one object over another?

Comment: A mathematically ideal fair die with half sides showing "1" and the other half showing "2" and a mathematically ideal fair coin do not vary at all in their randomness.  Concerns about length of time in the air or anything of the sort are irrelevant.

Comment: The time is irrelevant (assuming as JMoravitz does that the die and coin are fair). Uncertainty is a binary and exists the moment you start the flip/toss, it's not something that increases the more time it takes to complete the flip/toss.

Comment: Now... as for reality instead of dealing with ideals... a coin can in fact land on its edge rather than on one of the faces.  It is rare, but it does happen.  A die similarly can land on neighboring stacks of papers or game boards and be "cocked", not having landed evenly (*and according to many house rulings require a rethrow*).  In my experience, the coin landing on its edge is far less common in a dirty environment while the dice landing cocked is less common in a clean environment (*e.g. in a dice tray*).  As for fairness, I have not seen detailed statistics on this.

Comment: I would trust companies like Chessex to have plenty of experimental evidence to show their dice are very close to fair (*within a rather precise margin of error*) as it would negatively impact them as a brand if it was found that the dice were imbalanced.  Coin minters of currency on the other hand have little reason to concern themselves with maintaining fairness of the coin.  I would trust a die more than I would trust a coin to be balanced.

Comment: Thank you for the Analysis!  I did not even consider the coin landing on its side or the dice landing cocked.  Also, the thought of a company making dice and testing for fairness is very interesting.

Comment: Now you got me curious.  [I found this blogpost](https://www.awesomedice.com/blogs/news/d20-dice-randomness-test-chessex-vs-gamescience) looking at some experimental results comparing the fairness of Chessex dice vs GameScience dice.  I'm a little disheartened by the results, but I guess the "lucky d20" might really be more than confirmation bias.  Still, for everyday use, they seem close enough to fair that it shouldn't much matter.

Comment: You might look at [this](https://news.stanford.edu/news/2004/june9/diaconis-69.html)

Comment: Along the same line as the comment by @RobertIsrael, you might be interested in this YouTube video: [How random is a coin toss?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYnJv68T3MM)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specify in mathematical terms what you mean by "random" and "better" and "easier time generating," and unless you are talking about an idealized die and idealized coin, then your question is not really about mathematics.

Here are some ways in which we might be able to formulate your question mathematically:

1. If we specify the geometry and mass of the coin and the die, and for a fixed velocity choose a random angle and orientation to throw them, on average, what is the time for them to "settle?"  This is a physics question and depends on a number of additional model parameters such as the proportion of energy lost per collision.
2. Assuming the coin and die each have a known and idealized probability distribution, and ignoring the amount of time to generate realizations from each,  would a third observer who is furnished with samples of arbitrarily large but equal size from each object but not the information about which object generated which sample, be able to distinguish the two?  This is a mathematical question.

Answer (score 0):

Randomness of these objects are due to the chaotic nature of their motion, especially when bouncing on a surface. Chaotic motion amplifies the initial conditions exponentially, so that even thermal noise could make a change to the outcomes.

Anyway, I would not be surprised that a well trained player, in repeatable conditions and able to choose the initial position could obtain a bias in the drawings. (Especially if catching the coin in hand, or throwing the dice on a short distance.)

But I have no insight on which could be most easily tricked.

---

It is believed that quantum effects can generate perfectly unpredictable events. Note that modern Intel Processors include a RNG based on such effects.